# What is the correct name for this instrument?

Tags: instruments, brass, trombone

I guess it's some type of trombone, but I can't find its correct name anywhere.

[image]

---

P.S. If you're wondering, here's where I got this shot from:

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is apparently called a  [contrabass valve trombone](https://mimo-international.com/MIMO/detailstatic.aspx?RSC_BASE=IFD&RSC_DOCID=MINIM_UK_UEDIN_2532&TITLE=%2Fcontrabass-valve-trombone-nominal-pitch-18-ft-b&_lg=eu-ES), or sometimes a [cimbasso](https://helmut-voigt.com/deutsch-cimbasso/) if I am correct.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Any particular composer or period of music history it was favoured by/in?

Comment: @Tim Maybe a good new question ;) ?

Comment: @Tim: probably Wagner 

Comment: Interesting, it appears to have rotary valves like a French horn instead of piston valves like regular valve trombones.

Comment: @johnbelzaguy Might actually be the difference between the CVT and the cimbasso!

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on "types of trombone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_trombone#Cimbasso) has more information for the curious.

Comment: @Tim I forgot to include the link to the wiki article with more info, Michael Siefert put it in. Seems like the shape is the main difference (if you trust wiki). The two have the same range ans can have either piston or rotary valves. Apparently Verdi didn’t dig the tuba, lol.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy For that matter, there are piston-valved French horns too.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes I’m aware. The rotary valves on the cimbasso just caught my eye so I commented on it.

Answer (score 19):

This is a [cimbasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_trombone#Cimbasso) (a valve contrabass trombone). The instrument is mainly used in Verdi's operas (and one opera each by Bellini and Puccini). The modern instrument has six rotary valves and is normally pitched in F, but there are also instruments in B-flat (a fifth lower). Both instruments can be heard here (the low B-flat is the one with the smaller bell, lower right):

Mattis Cederberg of the West German Radio Big Band uses a cimbasso for jazz:

Comment: Interesting that it's used in both *Nabucco* and *Norma*, so I may have heard one twice without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

The instrument shown is called a cimbasso, an instrument basically created by Verdi as something similar to the contrabass trombone. It's pretty rare!

Comment: Glad to see you're getting active on the site. Since your answer here duplicates the ones already given, just a reminder/suggestion to read the other posts first. What's unique here is your comment that Verdi invented the instrument. If that can be documented, it would add something unique not in the other answers.

Comment: @Aaron From the Wikipedia article referenced from my answer: "Verdi ... developed an instrument with the firm Pelitti"